# Packing and moving an office

Tags: job-description

Due to Management not maintaining our building we are now basically condemned and are forced to move.  They are expecting us to pack everything and move in a span of two weeks while maintaining our regular work schedule (you can pack and move on your downtime). Due to COVID-19 we have downsized from 5 to 2.  Can my employer force me to pack and move office equipment, charts, etc. ? My job description says that I must be able to lift 30lbs and I am responsible for 'other duties as needed. I am also having to use my own vehicle to move boxes and such.

Comment: What legal jurisdiction?

Comment: Is "owning and operating a vehicle" part of your contract? "Other duties" does include things you *do*, not things you *own*. So, driving a car should be reasonable, driving *your own car for the company* is not.

Comment: **Can my employer force me to pack and move office equipment, charts, etc.?** - Not likely on your own time with your personal vehicle, but how will our answers help you? What do you plan to do with this information? How will anything we tell you change this scenario? I'm asking because it isn't likely that anything we say will give you anything of use to get out of this or to get them to allow you to do it during work hours using company provided transportation.

Comment: I think this is a case where you'll need to give them the opportunity to set priorities. Send an email: "Hi Boss, due to packing, moving and unpacking furniture requiring (x) days of work, one of my other deliverables will need to be delayed, here's a list, what can be de-prioritised?". Even if they say nothing can be de-prioritised, it's on record that you raised this as an issue. If by 'downtime' they mean 'outside of working hours', have them clarify that in writing, then ask how to submit your overtime forms.

Comment: How are you intending to pack your computer and monitors while continuing to work?

Answer (score 6):

Your job description says "duties as needed". I'd argue that that probably includes packing up an office for a move, provided that you are not lifting dangerously heavy items.

However, I would also argue that it *doesn't* include doing so in your own time, so that you can work on company time, and *definitely* doesn't include using your own vehicle for transporting the stuff. In fact, in most places, this latter one will invalidate your car insurance, and should you have an accident, you won't be covered.

Sure you can get precious, and say that that's not what you were hired to do, but that's not likely to go over well.

As commented, though, a lot will depend on where in the world you are.